# Problem with corflags on interop library after VS upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-2010, corflags

I converted my visual studio solution from 2008 to 2010. A project has a reference to ShDocVw.  When I run the program I get a BadImageFormatException.  Googling led me to check the interop library with corflags:

```
corflags Interop.ShDocVw.dll

Version   : v2.0.50727 
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 3
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 1
Signed    : 0
```

Sure enough, the 32BIT flag is set so my application built as Any CPU on 64-bit machine cannot load this library.  If I run corflags /32BIT- I can turn off the 32BIT flag and everything works just fine.  The question is, why is this Interop library generated with that flag set?  I didn't have that problem with VS2008, this only started happening after the upgrade.

More importantly, how can I fix it so that I don't have to run corflags to turn the bit off?  I assume that it is probably due to some MSBuild-fu that I don't understand very well.  I haven't been able to spot anything, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after the upgrade the **<PlatformTarget>** tag is not set in certain **<PropertyGroups>** in the C# project files and it apparently defaults to x86.  So, to fix this go to the project Properties -> Build tab and set Platform Target to something other than AnyCPU, save it.  Now set it back to AnyCPU and save it.  The **<PlatformTarget>** will be written to the project with the value of AnyCPU and all is well.

[Here is where I found the answer.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/clr/thread/4684e073-e71d-4bd1-a568-f626c32079d7)